# Timer in assembly using interrupts

Tags: assembly, timer, interrupt, x86-16, tasm

I am trying to create a code that prints '0' waits 4 seconds and then prints '1'.
I don't have to take into account the hours. **I need the code to work when the seconds are bigger or equal than 56.**
That's the code I wrote but I can't figure out what's the problem so it will work when the seconds are bigger or equal than 56.

```
IDEAL

MODEL small

STACK 100h

DATASEG

; -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --


; -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

CODESEG

start:

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

; -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
;print zero
mov dl,'0'
mov ah,2
int 21h
;reads the time
mov ah,2ch
int 21h
;checks if the seconds are bigger or equal to 56
cmp dh,56
jae l2 


;moves the seconds+4 to bl
 mov bl,dh
 add bl,4
 l3:
 ;check if the time is equal to bl
 l1:
 mov ah,2ch
 int 21h
 cmp dh,bl
 jl l1
 ;print one
 mov dl,'1'
 mov ah,2
 int 21h

 ; -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

 exit:

 mov ax, 4c00h

 int 21h

 l2:
 add dh,4
 sub dh,60
 mov bl,dh
 jmp l3

 END start
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: A much simpler way to do this, in my opinion, would be to use the BIOS interrupt 15h, function 86h. This waits for the specified number of microseconds, and does not return control to your code until that interval has elapsed. Put the low word of the microsecond interval in DX and the high word of the microsecond interval in CX, then put 86h in AH, and call `int 15h`. That's all the code you need---about 4 lines!

Comment: Your problem is that 56 seconds is greater than 0 seconds. When the start time is 56 seconds you calculate a stop time of 0 seconds. You then wait until the current time is greater than or equal 0, but that's always true so you don't wait at all. You want to check until the difference between the current time and the start time is greater than or equal to 4. That is wait until `(start_secs - cur_secs) % 60 >= 4`.

Comment: Is the goal here to use BIOS or DOS INTs to call timer related functions, or should the goal be to hook into the timer interrupt (INT 8), and use an interrupt routine to drive a counter or possibly to implement a delay?

Comment: The goal here is to learn to use the mov ah,2ch and int 21h

Comment: @RossRidge Correct me if I'm wrong but dh can go up to 59 and then turn into  0 again. So when I add 4 to 56 and subtract 60 the result is 0. So I just wait until dh is 0.

Comment: You're not waiting until DH is 0, you're waiting until DH is greater than or equal to 0, which is always true.

Comment: Thank you! I understood my problem.